# Apply a formula in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new in spark and I have some doubts about working with df.
My problem is that I need to apply a formula to a pyspark df column using values from other columns.
I have following df

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| count1| count2|val__00|val__01|val__02|val__03|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      3|      1|    1.0|    0.0|    8.0|    0.0|
|      4|      2|    0.0|  1.379|   1.49|  1.373|
|      2|      5|    0.7|    0.0|   70.4|    0.0|
|      1|      8|    0.0|    4.0|    0.0|    0.0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I need to apply following formula to columns val__xx for each row:

```
val__xx = val__xx + (count1*count2)
```

so final df will be

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| count1| count2|val__00|val__01|val__02|val__03|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      3|      1|    4.0|    3.0|   11.0|    3.0|
|      4|      2|    8.0|  9.379|   9.49|  9.373|
|      2|      5|   10.7|   10.0|   80.4|   10.0|
|      1|      8|    8.0|   12.0|    8.0|    8.0|
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I think to apply an udf function but I don't know how to pass more than one column. Is it possible to make a function to pass more than one column?
I have implemented code below but I don't know hot to pass cols val__xx

```
def calculate(c, count1, count2):
   return c + (count1*count2)  

calculateUDF = udf(lambda x: calculate(x, count1, count2))

df_final = df.apply(calculateUDF(col(val__xx????), col(count1), col(count2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do using `withColumn` in a for loop, no need for a udf.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

for i in range(4):
    df = df.withColumn(f'val__0{i}', f.col('count1') * f.col('count2') + f.col(f'val__0{i}'))

df.show()

+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+                                 
|count1|count2|val__00|val__01|val__02|val__03|
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|     3|     1|    4.0|    3.0|   11.0|    3.0|
|     4|     2|    8.0|  9.379|   9.49|  9.373|
|     2|     5|   10.7|   10.0|   80.4|   10.0|
|     1|     8|    8.0|   12.0|    8.0|    8.0|
+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

If your your 'value' columns reaches double digits you'll need to left pad the `i` with zeros.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer! It works!